# Is Flutter Dart compiled native or transpiled to Kotlin or Swift?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, cross-platform

Upon opening APK files I've found code in Kotlin, instead of Dart. And upon opening IPA files, finding Swift code instead of Dart.

What happens to the Dart code? Is it transpiled to the native SDK language?

If so, what is use of the libflutter.so and libapp.so? assuming that the application is now native, why would it still need the Dart runtime?

Comment: Yeah, right. Flutter SDK has done converting work for us already, just code in Dart then when compiling it will transform to Kotlin or Swift to run on the native platforms.

Comment: then what is use of the libflutter.so and  libapp.so because it contains the dart runtime as the dart code is convert to the native code then what is use of dart runtime in the engines c/c++ as it comes with the app

Answer (score 6):

[Flutter](https://flutter.dev) is an SDK developed by Google. It's a Dart library built to provide GUIs with native look & feel. This is achieved via the Flutter Engine (using [Google Skia](https://skia.googlesource.com/skia)), last I saw built in C++. However, interfacing calls to the native platform are done via their specific SDKs (and native languages, such as Swift and Kotlin/Java).

[Dart](https://dart.dev/) is both a programming language and a platform (Dart VM). And [it can be run in many ways](https://dart.dev/overview):

1. Dart Virtual Machine: On Windows, macOS and Linux, using Just-in-Time.
2. Native: Using *dart2native*, Dart can be compiled to self-contained, single file, native executables.
3. JavaScript: Using a source-to-source compiler, Dart code converts to JavaScript and can be run in most web browsers.
4. AOT / Ahead-of-Time: This is fully native to mobile platforms (iOS / Android) and used mostly for delivery to app stores.

*Under the hood, there's a lot of solid magic going on. It may include converting some of your GUI specific related code to native. Enjoy!*

Comment: then what is use of the libapp.so and libflutter.so files in the lib folder of the Apk in the app if the app is convert to the the native code .                                                                                    If it's is converted to the native it can use the android runtime  then what is the use of the libflutter.so file as the libfluter.so contains the dark Vm

Comment: The code itself is still native, doesn't mean it no longer has dependencies on libraries. Please see in my response the reference to such.

Comment: " (using Google Skia)," so that's why Darts only supports 2D no 3D OpenGL support, so far I need to go native for anything 3D?

Comment: @ShifraSec Skia is 2D, but doesn't mean you can't make OpenGL work, check the link below. If you still have questions about it, I would recommend posting it as its own question in StackOverflow. https://github.com/skui-org/skui/issues/13